# Elasticsearch / Kibana: NoShardsAvailableException

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am setting up a 7 node cluster with 3 Masters / 3 Data / 1 [Coordinating node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/production.html#load-balancing)

The cluster is deployed on AWS with ec2 discovery plugin.
The nodes are using Amazon Linux 2 and the ES/Kibana versions are `6.4.2`

`kibana.yml`:

```
server.port: 8080
server.host: 10.11.11.11 # private ip of node
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
```

`/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

```
cluster.name: elastic-cluster-prod

path.data: /elastic_data

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true

network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.ec2.endpoint: ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
discovery.ec2.host_type: private_ip
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
node.master: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
s3.client.default.endpoint: s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
transport.tcp.port: 9300
node.name: es-prod-coord
action.auto_create_index: true
transport.host: _ec2:privateIp_
```

However, although all other nodes seem healthy, coordinating node fails:

`kibana.log`

```
{"type":"error","@timestamp":"2019-01-03T08:18:17Z","tags":["warning","stats-collection"],"pid":2907,"level":"error","error":{"message":"[no_shard_available_action_exception] No shard available for [get [.kibana][doc][config:6.4.2]: routing [null]]","name":"Error","stack":"[no_shard_available_action_exception] No shard available for [get [.kibana][doc][config:6.4.2]: routing [null]] :: {\"path\":\"/.kibana/doc/config%3A6.4.2\",\"query\":{},\"statusCode\":503,\"response\":\"{\\\"error\\\":{\\\"root_cause\\\":[{\\\"type\\\":\\\"no_shard_available_action_exception\\\",\\\"reason\\\":\\\"No shard available for [get [.kibana][doc][config:6.4.2]: routing [null]]\\\"}],\\\"type\\\":\\\"no_shard_available_action_exception\\\",\\\"reason\\\":\\\"No shard available for [get [.kibana][doc][config:6.4.2]: routing [null]]\\\"},\\\"status\\\":503}\"}\n    at respond (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:307:15)\n    at checkRespForFailure (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:266:7)\n    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:159:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.bound (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)\n    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)"},"message":"[no_shard_available_action_exception] No shard available for [get [.kibana][doc][config:6.4.2]: routing [null]]"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-01-03T08:18:17Z","tags":["warning","stats-collection"],"pid":2907,"message":"Unable to fetch data from kibana_settings collector"}
```

`/var/log/elasticsearch/<cluster-name>.log`

```
[2019-01-03T08:19:17,969][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] path: /.kibana/doc/config%3A6.4.2, params: {index=.kibana, id=config:6.4.2, type=doc}
org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: No shard available for [get [.kibana][doc][config:6.4.2]: routing [null]]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$AsyncSingleAction.perform(TransportSingleShardAction.java:207) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$AsyncSingleAction.start(TransportSingleShardAction.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction.doExecute(TransportSingleShardAction.java:95) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction.doExecute(TransportSingleShardAction.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.doExecute(TransportAction.java:143) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.apply(SecurityActionFilter.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:139) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:87) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:76) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:407) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.get(AbstractClient.java:499) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.document.RestGetAction.lambda$prepareRequest$0(RestGetAction.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:97) [elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.rest.SecurityRestFilter.handleRequest(SecurityRestFilter.java:72) [x-pack-security-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:239) [elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.tryAllHandlers(RestController.java:335) [elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:173) [elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:538) [transport-netty4-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:137) [transport-netty4-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:68) [transport-netty4-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) [netty-handler-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:545) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:499) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

**edit**:

```
curl -XGET http://<host>:9200/_cat/indices?v
health status index   uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   .kibana Z04tBGcDQ7OLRqjciAqiDA   1   1   


curl -XGET http://<host>:9200/_cat/shards?v
index   shard prirep state      docs store ip node
.kibana 0     p      UNASSIGNED               
.kibana 0     r      UNASSIGNED   

curl -XGET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://<host>:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain -d '{"index": ".kibana","shard": 0,"primary": true}'
{"index":".kibana","shard":0,"primary":true,"current_state":"unassigned","unassigned_info":{"reason":"INDEX_CREATED","at":"2019-01-03T09:26:19.270Z","last_allocation_status":"no_attempt"},"can_allocate":"no","allocate_explanation":"cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes"}
```

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET <host>:9200/_cat/indices?v` and `curl -XGET <host>:9200/_cat/shards?v` ?

Comment: @Val I have updated with the relevant outputs my question

Comment: There you go your Kibana shards are UNASSIGNED. What about this `curl -XGET <host>:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain -d '{"index": ".kibana","shard": 0,"primary": true}'` ?

Comment: updated my post again

Comment: duh...I made all my nodes `master` by mistake! thanks for your feedback! most likely will delete the question unless you 'd like to post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most likely your Kibana shards are not allocated. You can check if some or all of your shards are `UNASSIGNED` using `curl -XGET <host>:9200/_cat/shards?v`.

Once you confirm that, there could be many reasons, but it is easy to find out using the [cluster allocation explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-allocation-explain.html):

```
curl -XGET -H 'Content-type: application/json' <host>:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain -d '{
  "index": ".kibana",
  "shard": 0,
  "primary": true
}'
```